# Including an editable=False field in Django Model Form as HiddenInput

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So we recently upgraded to Django 1.4 and it's come to my attention that there was a change on how model fields with editable=False are handled with Model Forms.

If I have a user model with:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id              = UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4str)
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Where UUIDField automatically has the kwargs['editable'] = False, and then try to make a Model Form of that:

```
class UserFormSelf(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('id', 'name',)
        widgets = {
        'id': HiddenInput()
            }
```

I get the following error when running:

"Unknown field(s) (id) specified for User"

Per the docs, [If False, the field will not be displayed in the admin or any other ModelForm. Default is True.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#editable). However, since the field is Hidden and only used so I can determine which User is being edited, there should be a way to allow it in the form, correct?

I really don't want id to be editable, however if this is the only solution I may have to. Perhaps it could be editable, but then on save if it isn't a new object, I induce an exception. Would like to figure out if it's possible to do it with editable=False first though.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Apparently it is not possible to check to see if the id field has been edited and write a custom "editable=False" on pre_save, as pre_save automatically thinks an object is new if it has a new id. If you can't provide an answer to the above, but know how to do this, please let me know as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just display the value yourself?  Forms are for input/output, and presumably your UUID will be calculated on your end or known to the application, if the record already exists.  It's tough for me to give an example since you didn't provide your template code, but if you're using `as_p()` to show your form, just add something like `<p>Id: {{ object.id }}</p>` in the case when you're editing an existing object.